# if statement with timer not working

Tags: android, timer

I'm trying to get Button's background image and use it in `if statement`. and check the `if statement` every 1000 millisec. this is my code:

```
    final Button btn_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button btn_2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button btn_3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    final ImageView a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    final ImageView b = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);
    final ImageView c = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img3);


    class CheckCondition extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
                if (btn_1.getResources().equals(R.drawable.ic_luncher) &&
                    btn_2.getResources().equals(R.drawable.ic_luncher) &&
                    btn_3.getResources().equals(R.drawable.ic_luncher)){

                a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else
            {
                a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new CheckCondition(), 0, 1000);
```

But it just doesn't work. `imageviews` are always invisible even when `if statement` it's true.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is it coming inside if statement? did you check that?

Comment: you are using equals method in wrong way. You cannot compare by this way

Comment: Are you sure it's btn_1, btn_2, btn_3 you need to check if they have an image and not  buttong a, b, c since buttons a b c have images and not buttons btn_1, btn_2 and btn_3.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed can you explain more please?

Comment: @ArminSuljovikj yesi'm sure, i've set background image for those buttons

Comment: btn_1.getResources().equals(R.drawable.ic_luncher) is always false.

Comment: What do you mean by this `btn_1.getResources().equals(R.drawable.ic_luncher)` I dont get what you want to compare!

Answer (score 1):

It always return you false cause you are comparing false return type "Resource"(getResource) and "int"(drawable).

```
Resources resources = btn_1.getResources();
int drawable = R.drawable.ic_luncher;
```

If you are looking for similar drawable comparison than [getConstantState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getConstantState()) can help you to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use tags.

For example

```
button1.setTag("R.drawable.ic_luncher");
button2.setTag("R.drawable.ic_luncher");
button3.setTag("R.drawable.ic_luncher");

if (button1.getTag() == "R.drawable.ic_luncher" && button2.getTag() == "R.drawable.ic_luncher" && button3.getTag() == "R.drawable.ic_luncher") {

 a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```